# Как создать такой массив программно?

Tags: php, массивы, json

Как создать такой массив программно (php)?

```
{"response": {
        "count": 16,
        "items":[{
        "id": "1",
        "is_dir": "true"        
        },{
        "id": "2",
        "is_dir": "false"   
        }]  
    }
    }
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словами "такой"? В точности такой? Или размеры должны быть такими?

Comment: в точности ну или другие значения. ну чтобы структура была

Comment: @AnonimAnonim это же не массив, а json-строка. Вам нужно её преобразовать в массив? Или наоборот, получить из массива такую json-строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например так :)

```
$isDir = true;
$items = array();
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
{
    $item = array();
    $item['id'] = ($i+1);
    $item['is_dir'] = $isDir;
    $isDir = !$isDir;
    array_push($items , $item);
} 

$response = array();
$response['response'] = array();
$response['response']['count'] = 16;
$response['response']['items'] = $items;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $response = json_encode([
        'response' => [
        'count' => 16,
        'items' => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'is_dir' => true
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'is_dir' => false
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);

print($response);
```